# How to apply OR conditions between two conditions in IAM policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Below is my IAM policy:

```
{​​​​​
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {​​​​​
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*",
            "Condition": {​​​​​
                "StringEquals": {​​​​​
                    "s3:ExistingObjectTag/custom:kypha": "${​​​​​aws:PrincipalTag/custom:kypha}​​​​​",
                    "s3:ExistingObjectTag/custom:pharma": "${​​​​​aws:PrincipalTag/custom:pharma}​​​​​"
                }​​​​​
            }​​​​​
        }​​​​​
    ]
}​​​​​
```

​
By default, AWS applies AND between two conditions ("s3:ExistingObjectTag/...."). But I required OR between them in such a way that if any of the conditions meet, then it will allow the specific action. How could I achieve this? any suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need **two separate statements** as your keys `s3:ExistingObjectTag/custom:kypha` and `s3:ExistingObjectTag/custom:pharma` are different:

```
{​​​​​
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {​​​​​
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*",
            "Condition": {​​​​​
                "StringEquals": {​​​​​
                    "s3:ExistingObjectTag/custom:kypha": "${​​​​​aws:PrincipalTag/custom:kypha}​​​​​"}​​​​​"
                }​​​​​
            }​​​​​
        },
        {​​​​​
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*",
            "Condition": {​​​​​
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:ExistingObjectTag/custom:pharma": "${​​​​​aws:PrincipalTag/custom:pharma}​​​​​"
                }​​​​​
            }​​​​​
        }        
        ​​​​​
    ]
}​​​​​
```